# Land subdivision calculations

Tags: gis

[image]
[image]

I have saved a map from QGIS containing a KML file and a Google satellite imagery layer into a SVG file which I then opened in Inkscape.

I'd like to do some measurements. I need to do an analysis of the land, where I divide the lot into smaller parcels with dimensions. Is it better to do this in QGIS or an SVG editor such as inkscape, or is there another program that I should be looking at?

Comment: This is more suited to the site [Geographic Information Systems](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RohitGupta, they said I should ask here!